# How to display toast message in react js only when the error is occured

Tags: reactjs

**Hi everyone,
am new to react js am working on to display toast message only when the error is occurred its more likely i want to display the errors in browser console log  which occurs in web page can anyone please suggest me a best way to do it or guide me on how to do it**

Comment: did you try something yet?

Comment: There are some react libraries for toast such as https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify. Give it a try..

Comment: @AbuSufian yes i tried using error handling but am not able to get the message but rather my whole application is stoppped working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This **[link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/toasts/)** shows you how to add a toast in React

And for the errors, you can just `console.log()`